# Minimum vertex cover in a Bipartite Graph

Tags: java, graph

I have written a function in Java to find minimum vertex cover in a bipartite graph. It is working on all the sample test cases I have used. However, due to lack of implementation and test cases online for this problem, I am not sure if it is correct or not.

Here is core part of the implementation. All the dependencies, such as `MaxMatching` class, are tested online and they are correct.

```
public class MinVertexCover
{
    private final BipartiteGraph biGraph;

    public MinVertexCover(BipartiteGraph biGraph)
    {
        this.biGraph = biGraph;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return ArrayList of integers which are part of min vertex cover
     */
    public ArrayList<Integer> minVertexCover()
    {
        // Step 1: Obtain all the edges part of the maximum matching
        MaxMatching matching = new MaxMatching(biGraph);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> edges = matching.maxMatchingEdges();

        // Step 2: Find all the unmatched vertices of set L and R
        boolean[] hasMatching = new boolean[biGraph.vertices];
        for (ArrayList<Integer> e : edges)
        {
            hasMatching[e.get(0)] = true;
            hasMatching[e.get(1)] = true;
        }

        boolean[] isCovered = new boolean[biGraph.vertices];

        // Step 3: Mark all the vertices of set R covered, which are connected to
        // all the unmatched vertices of set L
        for (int i = 0;i < biGraph.L;i++)
        {
            if (!hasMatching[i])
            {
                for (Graph.Vertex v : biGraph.adjacencyList.get(i)) isCovered[v.i] = true;
            }
        }

        // Step 4: Mark all the vertices of set L covered, which are
        // connected to an unmatched vertex of set R
        for (int i = 0;i < biGraph.R;i++)
        {
            if (!hasMatching[i+biGraph.L])
            {
                for (Graph.Vertex v : biGraph.adjacencyList.get(i+biGraph.L)) isCovered[v.i] = true;
            }
        }

        /* Step 5:
           Mark all the vertices of set R covered which are
               a: part of maximum matching
               b: are not matched with a covered vertex of set L
         */
        for (ArrayList<Integer> e : edges)
        {
            if (!isCovered[e.get(0)]) isCovered[e.get(1)] = true;
        }

        // Step 6: Add all the covered vertices to the vertex cover
        ArrayList<Integer> minVertexCover = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0;i < biGraph.vertices;i++) if (isCovered[i]) minVertexCover.add(i);

        return minVertexCover;
    }
}
```

Anyone who wishes to test the code locally will need to clone [my repo](https://github.com/AKSingh18/Graph/tree/review-min-vertex-cover). This points to review-min-vertex-cover branch which contains a pre-implemented bipartite graph in `GraphDemo.java` class. This can be used for reviewing purposes.

The algorithm has many dependencies and separating them is not a simple task.

---

Here are few resources I used to check if my implementation is correct (though I don't actually understand the algorithm). They may be of help to reviewers.

- [Kőnig's theorem - algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)#Algorithm) on Wikipedia
- [Algorithm for minimum vertex cover in Bipartite graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52819825/13618871) on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

For a proper review, it would be highly preferable if we had access to the other classes, such as `BipartiteGraph` and `MaxMatching`. Here are some thoughts on what you provided:

Abbreviations can be confusing. Prefer `MinimumVertexCover` to `MinVertexCover` and `MaximumMatching` to `MaxMatching`.

Classes not designed to be extended should be marked `final`.

I would expect this class to have a no-argument constructor and for the `minimumVertexCover` method to take a bigraph as an argument. As written, you need to instantiate the algorithm once for each graph, which doesn't make much sense to me.

Similar for `MaxiumumMatching`. In addition, to support unit testing, consider if `MaximumMatching` should really be an interface which is passed in to the constructor of `MinimumVertexCover`. This would allow a mock to manually control the exact matches returned without needing to rely on the algorithm.

In idiomatic Java, there's whitespace after a `;` unless it ends a line.

In idiomatic Java, an open curly brace is on the same line, not a new line.

`bigraph` is the capitalization used by math sources to refer to a bipartite graph. The capital `G` in the variable name is confusing.

Since the bigraph is mutable, a defensive copy would be preferable to
an unsafe copy. This code is vulnerable to threading issues.

Why does `minVertexCover` return an ordered collection which allows duplicates, when a minimum vertex cover is an unordered collection which does not allow duplicates? This should probably be a `Set` (not a `HashSet`, since clients shouldn't care about the implementation).

Similarly, `maxMatchingEdges` should be returning a `Set`.

When possible, code should assign to the most generic type available which meets the requirements (`List` or `Collection` rather than `ArrayList`).

Why is `Edge` not a top-level object with a vertex on either side? Tracking them as `List` is confusing.

`edge` would be a better variable name than `e`.

It appears that `BipartiteGraph` is hardcoded to only work on integers from 0 to the size of the graph? I'm not sure why it wouldn't accept generic types. This code could be reworked to break that dependency. It would also make the code easier to read if it was using well-named sets to track matched and covered vertices.

It's preferable to always include curly braces, even for single-line blocks. This removes a potential source of error and is easier to read. This is especially true for stacked control flow like having `for`, `if`, and a line of conditional code on the same line.

The code tends to directly expose variables. Classes should protect their internal values to prevent unexpected modifications, and also to allow flexibility for future modification. It is preferable to provide accessors for information a class wishes to expose.

Finally, the algorithm implementation looks correct to me, but I'm not heavily into graph theory, so I could be mistaken. A good battery of unit tests should give you some confidence that the algorithm is working as intended. You did say there weren't examples online, but it should be reasonably straightforward to generate the test cases yourself.

If you made all these changes, your code might look more like:

```
public final class MinimumVertexCover {

    private final MaximumMatchingAlgorithm maximumMatchingAlgorithm;

    public MinimumVertexCover(MaximumMatchingAlgorithm maximumMatchingAlgorithm) {
        this.maximumMatchingAlgorithm = maximumMatchingAlgorithm;
    }

    /**
     * @return Set of integers which are part of min vertex cover
     */
    public Set<Vertex> minimumVertexCover(BipartiteGraph bigraph) {
        // Step 1: Obtain all the edges part of the maximum matching
        Set<Edge> maximumMatchingEdges = maximumMatchingAlgorithm.matchingEdges(bigraph);

        // Step 2: Find all the unmatched vertices of set L and R
        Set<Vertex> unmatchedVertices = new HashSet<>();
        unmatchedVertices.addAll(bigraph.leftVertices());
        unmatchedVertices.addAll(bigraph.rightVertices());

        for (Edge edge : maximumMatchingEdges) {
            unmatchedVertices.remove(edge.leftVertex());
            unmatchedVertices.remove(edge.rightVertex());
        }

        Set<Vertex> coveredVertices = new HashSet<>();

        // Step 3: Mark all the vertices of set R covered, which are connected to
        // all the unmatched vertices of set L
        // Step 4: Mark all the vertices of set L covered, which are
        // connected to an unmatched vertex of set R
        for (Edge edge : bigraph.edges()) {
            if (unmatchedVertices.contains(edge.leftVertex())) {
                coveredVertices.add(edge.rightVertex());
            }
            if (unmatchedVertices.contains(edge.rightVertex())) {
                coveredVertices.add(edge.leftVertex());
            }
        }

        /* Step 5:
           Mark all the vertices of set R covered which are
               a: part of maximum matching
               b: are not matched with a covered vertex of set L
         */
        for (Edge edge : maximumMatchingEdges) {
            if (!coveredVertices.contains(edge.leftVertex())) {
                coveredVertices.add(edge.rightVertex());
            }
        }

        return coveredVertices;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the review. I will definitely look into unit tests. I will think over other suggestions as well.